# phpmyadmin - login issues

Tags: mysql

I have recently set up an installation of phpmyadmin, using the root username /password.

I have created a new user with the following:

```
User    Host    Password    Global privileges   Grant   Action
db_user     %   Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes
```

I have set the `auth_type` in the config.inc.php file to use `http`.

I can log into phpmyadmin with the root username and password, but not using the new user that I have created.

Do I need to configure anything further to allow this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually create the user through the command line and grant the right privileges.

All sorted now!